# session not callable in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the following network using tensorflow to classify the Belgian traffic signs everything looks fine except the run function in tensorflow:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed May 23 15:56:32 2018

@author: raed
"""

import tensorflow as tf
import os 
import skimage.io
from skimage import transform 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


#config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
#config_soft = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement =True)

def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) 
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.io.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

Root_Path = "/home/raed/Dropbox/Thesis/Codes/Tensorflow"
training_Directory = os.path.join(Root_Path,"Training")
testing_Directory = os.path.join(Root_Path,"Testing")
images, labels = load_data(training_Directory)

# Convert lists to array in order to facilitate information retrieval 
images_array = np.asarray(images)
labels_array = np.asanyarray(labels)

#print some information about the datasets 
print('Images Array Dimensions :',images_array.ndim)
print('Images Array length :',images_array.size)
print('Labels Dimensions :', labels_array.ndim)
print('Labels Size in Bytes :',labels_array.nbytes)
print('Number of labels :',len(labels_array))
print(images_array[0])
# plotting the distribution of different signs
sns.set(palette="deep") 
plt.hist(labels,62)
plt.show()

# Selecting couple of images based on their indices 
traffic_signs = [300,2250,3650,4000]
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
plt.show()

# Fill out the subplots with the random images and add shape, min and max values
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    print("Shape:{0},max:{1}, min:{2}".format(images_array[traffic_signs[i]].shape,
                                              images_array[traffic_signs[i]].max(),
                                              images_array[traffic_signs[i]].min()))

# Get unique labels
unique_labels = set(labels_array)

# initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

i=1
for label in unique_labels:
    image = images_array[labels.index(label)]
    plt.subplot(8,8,i)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('label:{0} ({1})'.format(label, labels.count(label)))
    i=i+1
    plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]


for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    print("Shape:{0},max:{1}, min:{2}".format(images28[i].shape,
                                              images28[i].max(),
                                              images28[i].min()))

#convert to grayscale
images28 = np.array(images28)
gray_images = skimage.color.rgb2gray(images28)

for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(gray_images[traffic_signs[i]], cmap="gray")
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# Modeling the neural network using TensorFlow
# prepare placeholders

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape =[None, 28 ,28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.int32, shape=[None])

#Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.layers.flatten(x)

##Fully connected layer , Multi-layer Perceptron (MLP)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 62, tf.nn.relu)

#Define loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits))

#define an optimizer (Stochastic Gradient Descent )
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

#convert logits to label indices
correct_prediction = tf.arg_max(logits,1)

#define an accuracy metric
accuracy =tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#########################################
print('######### Main Program #########')  
#########################################
print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
print("logits: ", logits)
print("loss: ", loss)
print("Optimizer:",optimizer)
print("predicted_labels: ", correct_prediction)

#images28 = np.asanyarray(images28).reshape(images28.shape[0],images28.shape[1],images28.shape[2])

# set the seed
tf.set_random_seed(1234)

# initialize the session in Tensorflow
first_session = tf.Session()
first_session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

#
for i in range(len(images28)):
    print('Epoch', i)
    _, accuracy = first_session.run([optimizer, accuracy], feed_dict={x:images28 , y:labels})
    if i % 10 ==0:
        print("Loss :", loss)
    print('Done With Epoch')
```

## first_session.close()

It seems I am feeding (4575, 28, 28,3) array into a placeholder of (?,28,28) , how can i fix that, the error now changed to the following :

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (4575, 28, 28, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_56:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28)'
```

Answer (score 1):

After a multiple trials,s it turned out to be a shape incompatibility between my array that I am trying to feed in and the placeholders, I used the following line to convert to gray scale before I flatten the array :

```
images28 = rgb2gray(np.array(images28))
```

There is no relation with the session.run() function , sincce it is already called. Now it is running perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The Session object is not callable, in order to evaluate you have to use `session.run`, in your case it would be something like:

```
_,accuracy_value = training_session.run([optimizer,
                   accuracy],feed_dict={x:images28_array, y:labels})
```

Comment: The same error persists , I don't think I need to call the run() function again since I initialized after I declared a session

Comment: @Raed I don't understand how you can have the same error when the code does something completely different (calling the session vs using run)

Comment: I am already running the session in this line :
        training_session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

Comment: Running the session is not something you do once, you do it every time you want to evaluate an expression. If you don't understand that, you have a conceptual problem.

Comment: I do understand that, I am just new to Tensorflow, and I ran the session before the call , but I am getting the same error

Comment: @Raed Your comment tells me you didn't understand my answer. You cannot be getting the same error with it.

Comment: Dear Matias , I change the code a bit now , I think the problem with the matices shapes not the session , I will update the code with the error message , please have a look